# Assign IDs to every entry in Org-mode

Tags: emacs, elisp, org-mode

[Org-mode](http://orgmode.org) has a bundled extension called [`org-id`](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-api/org-id-api.html), that implements global unique IDs for org-mode files. Every entry (a headline with its body) can have an ID property in its `:PROPERTIES:` drawer.

New ID for a single entry can be assigned with a function `org-id-get-create`.

**How can I assign an ID to every entry in an org-mode file?**

I could use an Emacs method of automating this, like a macro that calls `org-id-get-create` for every string starting with `*`. But I'd like to know if org-mode already has that capability. If not, please recommend the most idiomatic way to write an elisp code for this purpose.

Comment: why add ID's to all entries? (not saying it's a bad thing, just curious as I'm using ID's also).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I searched through the source and couldn't find anything obvious to do this already. I know it's used by *Org-mobile*, but I've not much experience of that.

By way of a starter, the following snippet will loop through all outline headings in the current file (Org-mode headings are basically standard Emacs outline headings), and add an ID if there's not already one there:

```
   (require 'org-id)
   (save-excursion
      (goto-char (point-max))
      (while (outline-previous-heading)
        (org-id-get-create)))
```

(If you're wondering why this loop goes backwards over the buffer rather than forwards, it's because the `while` loop will always call the outline navigation function at least once and if your Org-mode file starts with a heading this would be skipped if going forwards.)

This could be reasonably easily used within a loop over all the files known to the Org-mode agenda by looping over the entries returned by the function `(org-agenda-files)`, or added to a save hook for Org-mode files.

If someone more nimble-fingered than I doesn't get there first, if you can identify *when* you'd like the IDs added I could probably expand the above to be a complete solution.

Answer (score 18):

I agree with Stuart—I don't think there's anything in org-id to do this automatically so it really comes down to *when* you want to add the ids.

If you use [org-capture](http://orgmode.org/manual/Capture.html) to add all of your items then `org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook` is a logical place to put the code:

```
(add-hook 'org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook 'org-id-get-create)
```

Alternately you could do as Stuart suggested and add a save hook for org-mode files. I think the most idiomatic way to process all of the headlines in the file would be to use the [mapping API](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Using-the-mapping-API.html):

```
(defun my/org-add-ids-to-headlines-in-file ()
  "Add ID properties to all headlines in the current file which
do not already have one."
  (interactive)
  (org-map-entries 'org-id-get-create))
```

Finally we just need to add a `before-save-hook` which only runs in org-mode:

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (add-hook 'before-save-hook 'my/org-add-ids-to-headlines-in-file nil 'local)))
```

That should do it!

Comment: Your org-map-entries method is much neater than mine. I wasn't aware of that so thanks for teaching me!

Comment: Sure thing. That mapping API is pretty sweet.

Comment: Any reason `org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook` is preferred over `org-capture-after-finalize-hook`?