# Emacs orgmode Todo item automatically generates property drawer

Tags: emacs, org-mode, todo

I use Emacs `org-mode` to organise my todo list. Recently I found under each todo item it automatically generates a property drawer containing a key `ID` and the corresponding value, something like this:

```
    ** TODO meeting XXX  
       SCHEDULED: <2014-07-12 Sat 14:00>
       :PROPERTIES:
       :ID:       46673B08-F9D9-4966-B70A-A2ADBC2ADE0E
       :END:
       Entered on [2014-07-08 Tue 20:40]
```

I have no idea how this property drawer is generated, and I did not have it before. If delete it, next time I start Emacs to read the file, it will come back again. What would I do?

Comment: Check out this related thread where abo-abo was suggesting the usage of `org-id-goto` and `org-id-copy`:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/19620764/2112489  It looks like it may be the same thing you are seeing.

Comment: Do you mean I might perform `org-id-copy` accidentally? Is there any key binding for `org-id-copy`? @lawlist

Comment: I'm not sure exactly how you are triggering it, but I think it may be safe to assume that the library `org-id` is being used.  From a little bit of Googling and glancing at the source code of `org-id.el`, it appears that a common method of using `org-id` relates to links.  Perhaps you could open up `org-id` and see if anything in there looks familiar, starting with the a word search for `interactive` to help you jump from one function to the next.  Here is a link to the manual documentation section regarding links:  http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html

Comment: This is not something that Org will do by default, but can be enabled via configuration.  Could you share your org configuration from your init file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you have used MobileOrg?  If yes, that's the culprit (and that clutter is something more that keeps me away from using MobileOrg ATM).

Answer (score 0):

Posting your configuration file would definitely help diagnose what's causing this. For some, this is the desired behavior of the org-id package, which is explained in [Handling Links in the Org-mode Manual](http://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-links.html):

> The library org-id.el must first be loaded, either through org-customize by enabling org-id in org-modules, or by adding (require 'org-id) in your .emacs.

An init.el / .emacs file that enables this functionality, might for example, include the following:

```
;; Use global IDs
(require 'org-id)
(setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id t)

;; Update ID file .org-id-locations on startup
(org-id-update-id-locations)
```

Additionally, you could check your .emacs.d directory to see if there is a .org-id-locations file, which is generated by the org-id package.

To disable this behavior, you should remove all org-id package related code from your configuration files.

It's likely that this behavior occurs every time you use `(org-store-link)`, commonly bound to `C-l l`. You might also want to check out [Assign IDs to every entry in Org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340616/assign-ids-to-every-entry-in-org-mode)