# reference unique id across emacs org-mode files

Tags: emacs, org-mode

I have several .org files, and I'd like to be able to create links between them using an ID. I am using DOIs as  unique identifiers. I can link within a file by using properties:

```
* Paper 1
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: 10.1088/0953-8984/23/21/213001
  :END:

* Paper 2
  :PROPERTIES:
  :CUSTOM_ID: 10.1038/nphys2935
See also [[#10.1088/0953-8984/23/21/213001]]
```

Is there a way to make the custom_id global, so I can reference it from another file?

I think that org-id is what I need to go further, but I've found the documentation a little confusing. I tried adding the following lines in my `.emacs`

```
;; Use global IDs
(require 'org-id)
(setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id use-existing)

;; Update ID file .org-id-locations on startup
(org-id-update-id-locations)
```

but the file `.emacs.d/.org-id-locations` only has `nil`.

It seems like global links won't be automatically generated ([Assign IDs to every entry in Org-mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13340616/assign-ids-to-every-entry-in-org-mode)). I tried (with cursor on the heading) to use `M-x org-id-get-create`, but this does not seem to do anything.

EDIT: (Based on helpful comment)

Within one session, I can store and create links using `M-x org-store-link` while on the heading (`Paper 1` in my example above). Then I can use `M-x org-insert-link`, and type the ID to insert the link. The link looks like `[[id:10.1088/0953-8984/23/21/213001][Paper 1]]`. But I am running into two problems: (1) I'd like the ids to be stored automatically. (2) The links don't work when I close and re-open the file.

EDIT: A related question:

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2186/have-org-modes-exported-html-use-custom-id-when-linking-to-sub-sections-in-toc

Comment: Maybe it helps: `(setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id 'create-if-interactive)`. I use `org-store-link` and `org-insert-link`.

Comment: I think `org-store-link` and `org-insert-link` gets me partway there! But the links don't work once I close and reopen the file. Am I missing some configuration? (I'll edit my question with the new info)

Answer (score 6):

So here's the solution I came up with.

1. In my `.emacs` configuration, I have kept the same settings as in my question:

   ```
   (require 'org-id)
   (setq org-id-link-to-org-use-id use-existing)

   ;; Update ID file on startup
   (org-id-update-id-locations)
   ```
2. The files need to be part of the agenda list (or added to the list of additional files using `org-id-extra-files` ([See `org-id` documentation](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=lisp/org-id.el;hb=HEAD/%22%60org-id-extra-files%60%22)))
3. Use `ID` instead of `CUSTOM_ID` in the `PROPERTIES` drawer:

   ```
   * Paper 1
     :PROPERTIES:
     :ID: 10.1088/0953-8984/23/21/213001
     :END:
   ```
4. Each ID needs to be created (if necessary; in my case I already have them), and a link added to the ID file (links are stored in `.emacs.d/.org-id-locations`). This is done using `org-id-get-create`: with the cursor on the heading, call it using

   ```
   M-x org-id-get-create
   ```
5. Link to an ID using `[[id:10.1088/0953-8984/23/21/213001][Paper 1]]`.

I have to think a little bit more about when I'd like the ID to be created; I can automate the process by tying the ID storing to another function that I'll do to all the headings.

Comment: So it looks like it's NOT recommended to use ID in property drawers (http://orgmode.org/manual/Special-properties.html#Special-properties). I'm working on a new solution.

Comment: Looks like in the new version org-id uses ID property:
"In addition or alternatively, depending on the value of org-id-link-to-org-use-id, create and/or use a globally unique ‘ID’ property for the link" in 

[org guide][1]


  [1]: https://orgmode.org/manual/Handling-Links.html#DOCF29